# For MAC address filtering, why do we only need the mac address of the ethernet adapter instead of the laptop's mac address?

Tags: mac, ethernet, mac-address

So I understand every device that has a NIC will also have a MAC address which means laptops and Ethernet adapters will also have a MAC address. And a MAC address is needed for the sysadmin to authorize the device to connect to the network by Ethernet.

I got a MacBook which has no Ethernet port but I checked that it does have an Ethernet MAC address by running `ifconfig -a` which gave me a MAC address under `en0`. So why is the Ethernet MAC address from the MacBook not needed to enable Ethernet access to the laptop? Shouldn't the sysadmin need both the MAC address of the Ethernet adapter and the laptop's Mac Address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WiFi Adapters have MAC addresses as well, and it appears on MacOS systems without ethernet adapters, `en0` (and possibly en1, etc) are used to refer to the wifi adapter device(s).  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29958143/what-are-en0-en1-p2p-and-so-on-that-are-displayed-after-executing-ifconfig

The laptop won't have a MAC address, but its devices, like wifi or wired ethernet adapters will. I'm not quite sure where you are getting that impression from, but the MAC address is used specifically for layer2 functions of the network stack, so they are provided by network adapters, not the system software.